# R - Map Zoom Function, making the plot a circle rather than a square

Tags: r

I inherited some code off a colleague which I am trying to 'improve'.

Essentially it takes a map, and will then zoom in on a location, which then uses gridExtra to bind the map and zoomed map together.

It works, and the function is below:

```
map_zoom <- function(map, location="London", layout=rbind(c(1,  1, 1),
                                                          c(1, 3, 2),
                                                          c(1, 1, 1))) {

  ###
  #
  # Input:  a pre-existing map of the UK,
  #         and details of where to zoom in
  #
  # Output: the input map, with the zoomed in map inset
  #
  ###
  require(grid)
  require(gridExtra)

  #A data frame of where to zoom for various locations in the UK
  locations <- data.frame(rbind(
    c("London", 505000, 555000, 155000, 205000),
    c("Liverpool & Manchester", 330000, 400000, 370000, 440000),
    c("Leeds & Sheffield", 400000, 470000, 370000, 440000),
    c("Coventry & Birmingham", 380000, 450000, 250000, 320000),
    c("Edinburgh & Glasgow", 230000, 370000, 630000, 700000),
    c("Cambridge", 500000, 570000, 220000, 290000),
    c("Oxford", 420000, 490000, 170000, 240000),
    c("Bristol", 310000, 380000, 140000, 210000)))

  xlim <- as.numeric(locations[locations[,1] == location,2:3])
  ylim <- as.numeric(locations[locations[,1] == location,4:5])

  zoomed_map <- map +
    labs(subtitle = location) +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          #plot.margin = unit(c(2,-5,2,2), "cm"),
          plot.title = element_blank()) +
    coord_fixed(1, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)

  legend <- extract_legend(map)
  map <- map + theme(legend.position="none")

  map <- grid.arrange(map, zoomed_map, legend, 
                      layout_matrix = layout)



  return(map)

}
```

[image]

However, I want to make the right zoomed in map a circle instead of a square (and then hopefully add zoom lines between the circle and the coordinates that it is taking it from).

I am guessing the square (for London) comes from the vector:

```
c("London", 505000, 555000, 155000, 205000)
```

In the `map_zoom` function, is there an easy way to change the square into a circle, or would I have to find every long/lat in a certain radius to make a circle?

Thank you.

Edit:

The Extract_Legend function is:

```
extract_legend <- function(map) {

  ###
  #
  # Input:  a ggplot object with a legend
  #
  # Output: a ggplot object of just the legend
  # 
  ###

  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(map))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]

  return(legend)

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce: what does your `map` variable look like? Is there some default or package-specific tutorial value I can use?

Comment: Hey, its a geom_polygon object, using a shapefile from ONS. Is that enough? I could put all the code in the question, but its quite lengthy. Thank you btw

Comment: Since some value are hardcoded (the UK city coordinates, and location), it is possible to reproduce. Did you get the polygon file from a difficult to reproduce without the same shapefile. Where did you get this file? Also, a function`extract_legend` is called. Did you create this function or is it part of a package?

Comment: Hey, the shapefile was found here: https://data.gov.uk/dataset/2aa6727d-c5f0-462a-a367-904c750bbb34/nuts-level-1-january-2018-full-clipped-boundaries-in-the-united-kingdom

Comment: I have also added the Extract_legend function to my question. Thank you and sorry for the slow response! The map is just a cholopeth map assigning numbers to UK NUTS1 regions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the circle we can buffer the bounding box for, say, London by the radius of that bounding box about its centroid. That buffer can then be used to intersect our initial map data.

I'm not sure how you would go about adding 'zoom lines' between the circle and map because they are two separate plots.

I've used `sf` to do the reading in of the data and `rmapshaper` to simplify the shape for faster plotting. The file you linked has a level of detail that is probably not required for an overview of the UK.

**Create map data for testing**

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(rmapshaper)

nuts1 <- read_sf('http://geoportal1-ons.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/01fd6b2d7600446d8af768005992f76a_0.geojson')

# simplify geometries
nuts1_simp <- ms_simplify(nuts1,  keep=0.02)

# add some random data to make chloropleth
set.seed(100)
nuts1_simp <- nuts1_simp %>% mutate(value = sample(1:20,12)) %>%
  st_transform(27700)

# create initial map
my_map <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nuts1_simp, aes(fill  = value), col = 'black', size = 0.2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "transparent"))
```

**I left your extract_legend function unchanged:**

```r
extract_legend <- function(map) {  
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(map))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]

  return(legend)
}
```

**Updated map_zoom function:**

- added `stringsAsFactors = F` in locations data.frame as this was
  previously returning the factor levels when coercing to numeric
  rather than actual values.
- added calculations for the centroid of our location bounding box, as
  well as for the max radius of that `bbox`. This allows us to create a
  buffer with `st_buffer`
- retreived the data from the original map with `ggplot_build` and intersected with the buffer to create our circular shaped `zoomed_map`.

```r
map_zoom <- function(map, location="London", layout=rbind(c(1,  1, 1),
                                                          c(1, 3, 2),
                                                          c(1, 1, 1))) {
  require(grid)
  require(gridExtra)
  require(sf)

  #A data frame of where to zoom for various locations in the UK
  locations <- data.frame(rbind(
    c("London", 505000, 555000, 155000, 205000),
    c("Liverpool & Manchester", 330000, 400000, 370000, 440000),
    c("Leeds & Sheffield", 400000, 470000, 370000, 440000),
    c("Coventry & Birmingham", 380000, 450000, 250000, 320000),
    c("Edinburgh & Glasgow", 230000, 370000, 630000, 700000),
    c("Cambridge", 500000, 570000, 220000, 290000),
    c("Oxford", 420000, 490000, 170000, 240000),
    c("Bristol", 310000, 380000, 140000, 210000)),
    stringsAsFactors = F)

  xlim <- as.numeric(locations[locations[,1] == location,2:3])
  ylim <- as.numeric(locations[locations[,1] == location,4:5])

  location_bbox <- as.numeric(locations[locations[,1] == location,2:5])
  bbox_radius <- max((location_bbox[2] - location_bbox[1])/2, (location_bbox[4] - location_bbox[3])/2)
  bbox_centroid<- data.frame(x = (location_bbox[1]+location_bbox[2])/2, y = (location_bbox[3]+location_bbox[4])/2) %>%
    st_as_sf(coords = c('x','y'), crs = 27700)

  buffer <- st_buffer(bbox_centroid, bbox_radius)

  # get data from input map
  map_data <- ggplot_build(map)$data[[1]]%>% st_sf

  zoom_dat <- map_data %>% mutate(colid = factor(row_number())) %>% st_intersection(buffer)

  zoomed_map <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = zoom_dat, aes(fill=colid), size = 0.2, col='black')+
    scale_fill_manual(values=zoom_dat$fill)+
    labs(subtitle = location) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
    coord_sf(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim) +
    theme_minimal()+
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          plot.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "transparent")) 

  legend <- extract_legend(map)
  map <- map + theme(legend.position="none")

  map <- grid.arrange(map, zoomed_map, legend, 
                      layout_matrix = layout)



  return(map)

}


map_zoom(my_map, layout=rbind(c(1,  1, 1),
                              c(3, 1, 2),
                              c(1, 1, 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Chris, this is perfect. Thank you!... I also appreciate the lengthy information response with code. I can mess around with the zoom lines thing, it was secondary to getting the zoomed map as a circle. Thank you again!!!

Comment: No problem at all! One thing I now realise I overlooked is that I think it will require your input map to have a `geom_sf` layer so that the map data can be extracted with `ggplot_build`. Hopefully that won't be an issue.

Comment: Hey Chris, that is fine, not an issue at all :)